# Validations using DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two buttons in the form.I should validate only single model property in one button click and I should validate all model validations in other button click using data annotations in mvc3 razor.

Comment: Are you refering to client side validation? server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters based on the clicked button. Both of the buttons could be submit with different parameters' value. Based on the received value, controller could decide to validate which fields. You can remove fields from validation by ModelState.Remove("FieldName").

If you want to do this by ajax you can implement validation by Json.